# How to draw Scatter plot on top of background using Basemap

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to plot a scatter plot on a background using basemap. But it's overwriting the background. How do I retain the background?

I am using this code

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat=-80,urcrnrlat=80,llcrnrlon=-180,urcrnrlon=180,lat_ts=20,resolution='c')

m.bluemarble()

x, y = m(list(longitude), list(latitude))
plt.scatter(x,y,1,marker='o',color='Red')
plt.show()
```

But as soon as I run the scatter plot, its overwriting background image. How can I overlay the scatter plot on the image.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is how to plot a series of points on top of a raster map. Note that the bluemarble image is huge, so a full scale (1.0 or default) plot of it should be avoided. The code is based on yours.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

# make up some data for scatter plot
lats = np.random.randint(-75, 75, size=20)
lons = np.random.randint(-179, 179, size=20)

fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(8, 6.5)

m = Basemap(projection='merc', \
            llcrnrlat=-80, urcrnrlat=80, \
            llcrnrlon=-180, urcrnrlon=180, \
            lat_ts=20, \
            resolution='c')

m.bluemarble(scale=0.2)   # full scale will be overkill
m.drawcoastlines(color='white', linewidth=0.2)  # add coastlines

x, y = m(lons, lats)  # transform coordinates
plt.scatter(x, y, 10, marker='o', color='Red') 

plt.show()
```

The resulting plot:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to do this with a database on deaths from covid19, I have coordinates and number of deaths by location, what is the best way to plot this ?, I wanted to put a colorbar in the circles to indicate higher death rates

Comment: @VitorGonçalves You need 2 parameters, there is an example here: https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_demo2.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-scatter-demo2-py

Answer (score 2):

I realize it's an old question but in case anyone comes here with the same problem as I did.

The trick is to give a higher zorder for the scatter plot than for the `.bluemarble()`.

```py
m.scatter(x, y, 10, marker='o', color='Red', zorder=3)
```

More info here: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/misc/zorder_demo.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "overwriting the background". When you use `plt.scatter()`, it will plot the points over the map, so it will display the points over the background.

Just based off the code provided, I think you're issue here is `m(list(longitude), list(latitude))`.

If you have multiple points in a list, you want to loop over them.

```
lats = [32, 38, 35]
lons = [-98, -79, -94]
x, y = m(lons, lats)

for i in range(len(lats)):
   plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

If it's only one single point,

```
lat, lon = 32, -92
x, y = m(lon, lat)
plt.scatter(x, y, marker = 'o')
```

The styling of the points can be found in the matplotlib [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).